# How to cover UITabBar by UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

I have a segue between two views inside navigator controller and all of that inside tabbarcontroller. After segue i would like to cover the bottom tabbar by UIButton object like on the image below? Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: overlapping the `UITabBar` view with the `UIButton` instance, maybe? that can do the job for you.

Comment: You can hide the tab bar in your view controller, but it is not encouraged.  self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;  Then you can adjust the view size and display your own button.